# trying to match data from multiple callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of filenames in memory. I need to put out a list of those filenames, each filename in a button that when clicked will get the user to another window. The code below does that successfully. However, I also need to put alongside each filename button a description that is contained in the file. So, a callback to lookup the description field, and that works was well. What doesn't work is getting the call back that looks up the description to append it to the list item containing the filename button it came from. What I've found from 3 days of effort is that the order of the callbacks returning is seemingly random. So, how to get the file description to appear alongside the filename button is the problem. The code below would I think work if nTestText in the callback retained the value it had when the callback was issued, which it doesn't as presently constructed. So, how can I accomplish that. Or, maybe there's a whole better way. All suggestions welcome.

```
    $('#stServerLoads').empty();
    var nTestText=0;
    for (iLoad=0; iLoad<nLoadsServer; iLoad++) {
        filename=sServerLoadArray[iLoad];
        if (filename.substring(0,4)=='TEST') {
            $('#stServerLoads').append('<li><button class="load">' + filename.substring(0,filename.length-6) + '</button></li>');
            $('button').eq(iButton).on('click', {value:filename}, function(event) {
                ...
                window.location='load.html';
            });
            iButton++;
            $.getJSON('reports/' + filename,function(new_ld) {
                $('#stServerLoads li').eq(nTestText).append('&nbsp;&nbsp;' + new_ld.testtext);
                nTestText++;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the other ajax call?

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you're asking. I have the filenames, and use getJSON to read eachfile, one field of which is a description, which I then wish to append to the list item. If you're asking about the ajax call to get all the files names, that's many statements earlier in the program.

Comment: Oh, now I undestand you. I added a solution, check it please ;)

Comment: Its better to create a new button element with an all its properties including click/class/... then append it to the the #stServerLoads. This was your not using iButton++ which i think is out going out of scope.  ... if i understand correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, this would solve your problem:

```
$('#stServerLoads').empty();
for (var i=0; i<nLoadsServer; i++) {   //changed counter name here
  (function(iLoad){   //We add a closure
    filename=sServerLoadArray[iLoad];
    if (filename.substring(0,4)=='TEST') {
        $('#stServerLoads').append('<li><button class="load">' + filename.substring(0,filename.length-6) + '</button></li>');
        $('button').eq(iButton).on('click', {value:filename}, function(event) {
            ...
            window.location='load.html';
        });
        iButton++;
        $.getJSON('reports/' + filename,function(new_ld) {
            $('#stServerLoads li').eq(iLoad).append('&nbsp;&nbsp;' + new_ld.testtext);
        });
    }
  })(i);  //Calling closure function with counter value
}
```

The problem was that the iLoad var was getting overwritten due to the for loop. (As a solution try, you added the `nTestText` var, right?). But, by adding a *closure* each loop cycle has its own iLoad variable, so it doesn't get overwritten, and it works flawlessly :).

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. I was wondering if a closure was the solution, but haven't really figured them out yet. Bed time for this old man now, but I'll try implementing your solution in the morning when my aging brain works far better. Many thanks for the response.

Comment: Welcome. I visited your webpage and I got really impressed with what you're doing. I'd be honored to help you when possible for such a great project

Comment: You solution works great. Also, it enabled me to better understand closures. They make more sense when you see them solve an actual problem you need solving. Also, thanks for your offer, I'll keep it in mind. Do you happen to have any background in aviation, per chance? My email is terrywb@q.com.

Comment: Hi Terry, I don't know anything about aviation hehe, I'm only  software developer. But I can help you in things like this question, I know js and jquery really well. My email is edgarinvillegas@hotmail.com . My respect for you, I know people with a third of your age, that can't learn even half of what you have in your code. Congrats